# Trouble with function return type

Tags: rust, types

I am having trouble with creating a function that returns the following Gradient type (https://docs.rs/nannou/latest/nannou/color/gradient/struct.Gradient.html) from the nannou. I now realize this is going to be a problem for me in general with complex generics types.

I tried to use a trick I've seen, which is to call a non-existent function on a given type to have the compiler complain.

```
8 |     gradient.asdfasdf();
  |              ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `nannou::color::Gradient<nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb<nannou::color::encoding::Linear<Srgb>>>`
```

So great! My type must be `nannou::color::Gradient<nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb<nannou::color::encoding::Linear<Srgb>>>`

So then I created the function with that as the return type:

```
pub fn get_gradient(color_1: Rgb, color_2: Rgb) -> nannou::color::Gradient<nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb<nannou::color::encoding::Linear<Srgb>>> {
    let (r1, g1, b1) = color_1.into_components();
    let (r2, g2, b2) = color_2.into_components();

    Gradient::new(vec![lin_srgb(r1 as f32, g1 as f32, b1 as f32), lin_srgb(r2 as f32, g2 as f32, b2 as f32)]);
}
```

But then the compiler gives a new error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb: RgbSpace` is not satisfied
  --> examples/utils/color.rs:3:52
   |
3  | ...color_2: Rgb) -> nannou::color::Gradient<nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb<nannou::color::encoding::Linear<Srgb>>> {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `RgbSpace` is not implemented for `nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `RgbSpace`:
             (P, W)
             nannou::color::encoding::Srgb
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `RgbStandard` for `nannou::color::encoding::Linear<nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb>`
note: required by a bound in `nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb`
  --> /Users/brittcagnina/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/palette-0.5.0/src/rgb/rgb.rs:46:19
   |
46 | pub struct Rgb<S: RgbStandard = Srgb, T: Component = f32> {
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb`
```

I'm unsure how to proceed or even interpret this error. Not just with this particular type but in general. I'm having trouble with several other types in this library that use generics. What is the general strategy or principles needed to figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the naming in the `nannou` crate is quite a mess.

There are multiple `Rgb` types:

- `nannou_core::color::Rgb`, re-exported as:

  - `nannou::color::Rgb`
  - `nannou::prelude::Rgb`
- `palette::rgb::Rgb`, re-exported as:

  - `nannou::color::rgb::Rgb`
  - `nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb`

Further, there are multiple `Srgb` types:

- `palette::rgb::Srgb`, re-exported as:

  - `nannou::color::rgb::Srgb`
  - `nannou::prelude::rgb::Srgb`
- `palette::encoding::srgb::Srgb`, re-exported as:

  - `nannou::color::encoding::Srgb`

Note that especially in the `Rgb` case, even the docs are confused and tend to link to the wrong `Rgb` type.

Either way, the actual mistake you made is that you chose the wrong `Srgb` type:

```rust
use nannou::{color::Gradient, prelude::*};

pub fn get_gradient(
    color_1: Rgb,
    color_2: Rgb,
) -> nannou::color::Gradient<
    nannou::prelude::rgb::Rgb<nannou::color::encoding::Linear<nannou::color::encoding::Srgb>>,
> {
    let (r1, g1, b1) = color_1.into_components();
    let (r2, g2, b2) = color_2.into_components();

    Gradient::new(vec![
        lin_srgb(r1 as f32, g1 as f32, b1 as f32),
        lin_srgb(r2 as f32, g2 as f32, b2 as f32),
    ])
}
```

Alternatively, you don't even need the full form, because `Rgb<Linear<Srgb>, f32>` is just the long form of the actual return type of your `lin_srgb`, which is `LinSrgb<f32>`:

```rust
use nannou::{color::Gradient, prelude::*};

pub fn get_gradient(color_1: Rgb, color_2: Rgb) -> Gradient<LinSrgb<f32>> {
    let (r1, g1, b1) = color_1.into_components();
    let (r2, g2, b2) = color_2.into_components();

    Gradient::new(vec![
        lin_srgb(r1 as f32, g1 as f32, b1 as f32),
        lin_srgb(r2 as f32, g2 as f32, b2 as f32),
    ])
}
```